# Switching the PublicFolderDatabase on Exchange 2010; What can clients expect?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

Looking for insight into the effects of switching the publicfolderdatabase properties on a live Exchange 2010 database. Specifically what can the outlook clients (2007 and 2010 mixed) expect to see when this happens?

I will be doing limited testing, but I do want to know if anyone has encountered issues with non-responsive outlook clients and what you did to fix the issue (profile rebuild, resync, etc.).

I am trying to set expectations for this change, and communicate these issues to the help desk and to the users that might see an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: clients may have to restart outlook immediately following the change. But it seems that time heals all RPC wounds. Given about 10 or 15 minutes those problems went away without a restart of outlook.

This was tested on about 1000 mailboxes on 4 databases.